# How do I align the bullet points. Im using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

This is one of the projects from free coding camp on the frontend certficate.

I'm trying to align the bullet points of the `li` elements as well as make a footer at the bottom of the page using bootstrap.

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/TheCLeanGirraffe/pen/aWgbya)

Codepen html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mark Dean Tribute Page</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Keania+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="text-center main-header"> The Mark Dean <br /> Tribute Page</h1>
      <hr />
    <div class="row header ">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a><img class="header-image img-fluid" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/digg1kcz8/image/upload/v1496080685/20170529_121539_foudov.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a><img class="header-image img-fluid" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/digg1kcz8/image/upload/v1496080684/20170529_121729_p74ux7.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a><img class="header-image img-fluid"src="http://res.cloudinary.com/digg1kcz8/image/upload/v1496080685/20170529_121615_rpox2c.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="list-div" style="width = 25%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; ">
        <ul class="facts">
          <li><p>Mark Dean was born 1957 in jefferson city</p></li>
          <li><p>1982 Dean earned his master's degree in electrical engineering from Florida Atlantic university</p></li>
          <li><p>1992 Dean graduated and completed his doctorate from Stanford university</p></li>
          <li><p>1996 he was the first African American ever to rexeive the honor as an ibm fellow</p></li>
          <li><p>1997 he was honered with the black engineer of the year presidents award and was inducted into the hall of national inventors</p></li>
          <li><p>1999 Mark Dean lead a team of engineers to develop a gigahertZ chip</p></li>
          <li><p> Working closely with a colleague, Mark Dean developed USA industry standard architecture system bus</p></li>
          <li><p>Facts preview Nulla consequat purus velit, vitae lobortis nibh tempus at. Donec sollicitudin vitae lobortis nibh tempus at.  et sem id placerat.</p></li>
          <li><p>Facts preview Nulla consequat purus velit, vitae lobortis nibh tempus at.  vitae lobortis nibh tempus at. Donec sollicitudin et sem id placerat.</p></li>
          <li><p>Facts preview vitae lobortis nibh tempus at.  Nulla consequat purus velit, vitae lobortis nibh tempus at. Donec sollicitudin et sem id placerat.</p></li>
          <li><p>Visit <a href="https://www.biography.com/people/mark-dean-604036">here</a> to read more about Mark Dean</p></li>
         </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <footer class="footer navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <p>This was coded and Created by <em>Terrell Wright</em></p>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

codepen css:`

```
body {
  background-color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.main-header {
  font-family: 'Keania one', serif;
  color: rgb(82, 68, 50);
  font-size: 64px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;

}
.header-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 5px solid #3D3124;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.header {
  background-color: #3D3730;
  border-radius: 30px;

}

hr {
  background-color: #524432;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  height: 1px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.facts {
  text-align: center;

}


.facts li {
  display: list-style;
  list-style: circle;
  font-family: "Crimson Text", serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;


  /* bootstrap floats to left - for override

  */
}

.facts li:first-child {
  margin-top: 40px;

} `
```

Comment: What do you mean "align the bullet" exactly? You mean you want them to be closer to the text in the `li` in a wide screen?

Comment: Yeah sorry. I'm trying to align the li elements list-style position.

Comment: and you want the footer to be fixed on the bottom all the time? Or just visible at the bottom of the page when you scroll to the bottom? Maybe you can link me to the bootstrap version of what you're trying to do? It also looks like you're using some bootstrap 3 classes with bootstrap 4. Do you know what version you want to use?

Comment: something like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/JJrrPN

Comment: If you're using bootstrap, tag your question with `twitter-bootstrap`

Comment: Yeah!! Awesome is that bootstrap 3 or 4? And what is the difference at least concerning this project?

Comment: Be sure to `@` me, unless you're responding to an answer I posted, otherwise I won't be notified of your comment. Just randomly came back here and saw you replied. Submitted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bootstrap 4 (per your codepen), you can add `.d-flex.text-center.flex-column.align-items-center` to `.facts` and remove `text-align: center` from your css. That will put the contents of `.facts` in a flex column, center align the children and center align the text. That will put the bullets beside each flex child.

Then to fix the footer to the bottom of the screen, add `.navbar.fixed-bottom.justify-content-center;` to the footer to fix it to the bottom of the screen and vertically align the contents. Then assign a `height` to it, and use that `height` value as `padding-bottom` on `body` to make room for the menu.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mark Dean Tribute Page</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Keania+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body {
  background-color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.main-header {
  font-family: 'Keania one', serif;
  color: rgb(82, 68, 50);
  font-size: 64px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  
}
.header-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 5px solid #3D3124;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.header {
  background-color: #3D3730;
  border-radius: 30px;
  
}

hr {
  background-color: #524432;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  height: 1px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}


.facts li {
  display: list-style;
  list-style: circle;
  font-family: "Crimson Text", serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;
  
  
  /* bootstrap floats to left - for override
  
  */
}

.facts li:first-child {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.footer {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  height: 50px;
}

footer p {
  margin: 0;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="text-center main-header"> The Mark Dean <br /> Tribute Page</h1>
      <hr />
    <div class="row header ">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a><img class="header-image img-fluid" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/digg1kcz8/image/upload/v1496080685/20170529_121539_foudov.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a><img class="header-image img-fluid" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/digg1kcz8/image/upload/v1496080684/20170529_121729_p74ux7.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a><img class="header-image img-fluid"src="http://res.cloudinary.com/digg1kcz8/image/upload/v1496080685/20170529_121615_rpox2c.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="list-div" style="width = 25%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; ">
        <ul class="d-flex text-center facts flex-column align-items-center">
          <li><p>Mark Dean was born 1957 in jefferson city</p></li>
          <li><p>1982 Dean earned his master's degree in electrical engineering from Florida Atlantic university</p></li>
          <li><p>1992 Dean graduated and completed his doctorate from Stanford university</p></li>
          <li><p>1996 he was the first African American ever to rexeive the honor as an ibm fellow</p></li>
          <li><p>1997 he was honered with the black engineer of the year presidents award and was inducted into the hall of national inventors</p></li>
          <li><p>1999 Mark Dean lead a team of engineers to develop a gigahertZ chip</p></li>
          <li><p> Working closely with a colleague, Mark Dean developed USA industry standard architecture system bus</p></li>
          <li><p>Facts preview Nulla consequat purus velit, vitae lobortis nibh tempus at. Donec sollicitudin vitae lobortis nibh tempus at.  et sem id placerat.</p></li>
          <li><p>Facts preview Nulla consequat purus velit, vitae lobortis nibh tempus at.  vitae lobortis nibh tempus at. Donec sollicitudin et sem id placerat.</p></li>
          <li><p>Facts preview vitae lobortis nibh tempus at.  Nulla consequat purus velit, vitae lobortis nibh tempus at. Donec sollicitudin et sem id placerat.</p></li>
          <li><p>Visit <a href="https://www.biography.com/penavbar fixed-bottom justify-content-centerople/mark-dean-604036">here</a> to read more about Mark Dean</p></li>
         </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <footer class="footer navbar fixed-bottom justify-content-center">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <p>This was coded and Created by <em>Terrell Wright</em></p>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```